# unable to use special charachter '-' while generating XML

Tags: java, xml

I am Building XML Using JAVA,my element have few attribute and that attribute contains '-'

```
   but when setting attibute as :

  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder        = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc                   = builder.newDocument();
  Element dffgr=doc.createElement("diffgr:diffgram");
  dffgr.setAttribute("xmlns:msdata", "urn:schemas-­microsoft­-com:xml­-msdata".toString());
  dffgr.setAttribute("xmlns:diffgr", "urn:schemas-­microsoft­-com:xml­diffgram-­v1".toString());



'-' is replaced by 'xAD'
as  Output is :
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemasέicrosoftΣom:xmlΤiffgramζ1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemasέicrosoftΣom:xmlέsdata">


and desired output is :
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas­microsoft­com:xml­msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas­microsoft­com:xml­diffgram­v1">
```

Plese Help.

Comment: You're using soft-hyphen (U+00AD). Don't do that. Just use `-`, U+002D.

Comment: then how dffgr.setAttribute("xmlns:msdata", "urn:schemas-­microsoft­-com:xml­-msdata".toString());
  dffgr.setAttribute("xmlns:diffgr", "urn:schemas-­microsoft­-com:xml­diffgram-­v1".toString()); looks like ??

Comment: It's unclear why you're calling `toString()` on a string to start with. But basically those URNs should be using regular hyphens, not soft hyphens. Just change that.

Comment: Your "desired output" doesn't contain any hyphens at all, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this:

```
dffgr.setAttribute("xmlns:msdata", "urn:schemas-microsoft­-com:xml­-msdata");
dffgr.setAttribute("xmlns:diffgr", "urn:schemas-microsoft­-com:xml­diffgram-v1");
```

You are using the wrong character for `-`.